# Matlab error dialog when enter number instead of string

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I want to execute error dialog in my GUIDE GUI if the user enters in numbers instead of (or with) a string into the input box. I am doing this in a format of the if statement. How may I go about with this?

So far, I have checked for an empty box:

```
if isempty(editString)
errordlg("Please enter a name in the box. Thank you.', 'Error Code I');
return 
else if 
... % How would I check if they entered numbers instead of string, or mixed numbers with string?
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** `isa()` function doesn' t work in this case because all you read from `Edit Text` is `string` in other words `char`. Thus, if you even write `isa('123', 'integer')`, function returns `0` not `1`.

So go to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27537400/4240582)

---

You can use [`isa()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html) function in this case. This function examine the type of variable and returns logical output "1" or "0".

```
if isempty(editString)
errordlg("Please enter a name in the box. Thank you.', 'Error Code I');
return 
elseif isa(editString, 'integer')  || isa(editString, 'char')
% // Your statement
end
```

This is the table you can find MATLAB Fundamental Types:
[image]

[source](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html#)

Comment: Nevermind I'll post a new question because the issue has changed.