# Checking For Proper Input of `Edit Text` String

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, input, matlab-guide

I have a GUIDE GUI where I ask the user to enter in their name. It should execute an error dialog if they enter numerical characters, a mix of string and numerical characters, or a blank box.

The issue is that when I enter in numbers or a mix of string and numerical characters, then it is outputting `Error Code II` (1st `elseif` statement) instead of `Error Code III` (entering in numbers only) or `Error Code IV` (entering numbers and strings). Input would be greatly appreciated.

Here's essentially what I have:

```
if isempty(editString)
errordlg('Please enter a name into the text-box. We thank you in anticipation.',...
'Error Code I');
return
elseif char(editString) > 12
    errordlg('Please enter a name that is less than 12 characters long. Thank you.',...
 'Error Code II');
    return
elseif isa(editString, 'integer')
    errordlg('Please enter a name, not numbers. Thank you.', 'Error Code III');
    return
elseif isa(editString, 'integer') && isa(editString, 'char')
    errordlg('Please enter a name without mixing numbers & characters. Thanks.',...
    'Error Code IV');
else 
delete(gcf)    
gui_02
end
```

Comment: [Some names have numbers in them.](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: You're right. I think I should change it into a screen-name instead of real name to try to keep it conditionally accomodating. Thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `isa()` function doesn' t work in this case because all you read from `Edit Text` is `string` in other words `char`. Thus, if you even write `isa('123', 'integer')`, function returns `0` not `1`. Anyway, thanks to MATLAB there is a function: [`isstrprop()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html) determines whether string is of specified category such as `integer`, `char`..

Check the code below:

```
if isempty(editString)
    errordlg('Please enter a name into the text-box. We thank you in anticipation.', 'Error Code I');
    return
elseif length(editString) > 12
    errordlg('Please enter a name that is less than 12 characters long. Thank you.', 'Error Code II');
    return
elseif ~isempty(find(isstrprop(editString, 'digit'), 1)) & isempty(find(isstrprop(editString, 'alpha'), 1))
    errordlg('Please enter a name, not numbers. Thank you.', 'Error Code III');
    return

elseif ~isempty(find(isstrprop(editString, 'digit'), 1)) & ~isempty(find(isstrprop(editString, 'alpha'), 1))
    errordlg('Please enter a name without mixing numbers & characters. Thanks.', 'Error Code IV');
    return
end
```

It doesn' t look elegant but works.

Comment: I appreciate the pedagogical aspect of your answer and the change to the code. Thank you for your help on this one and the previous question!

Comment: Very nice mehmet, +1,

Comment: @Kamtal - Thank you (: As you can see, code doesn' t look good. Is there a nice way instead of using nested calls of functions: `isempty(find(isstrprop(...)))` ?

Comment: Yeah I saw but I couldn't come up with anything better. It's Okey!